# What's the opposite of "no-show"?

Tags: antonyms

It's called "no-show" if a guest doesn't appear. Is it right to call the opposite "show"?

Comment: Wouldn't it be "Showed Up"?

Comment: I'd say: *turn up*. The guest turned up at the meeting/party/event

Comment: Maybe we can borrow *arrivé*?

Answer (score 2):

"No-show" is a person who said they would be there, but never arrived.

The opposite of a no-show is someone who said they would NOT be there but who showed up anyway.

Answer (score 1):

attending,existing & present are the opposite words used related to guests.

Comment: +1 for *present*. But *no-show* can be a noun...

Answer (score 1):

In the context of an attendance list, show/no-show would be readable and has good parallelism